# React/Socket.io client not connecting to server when deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, heroku, socket.io

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBr-PybP_9c

Locally, the app works fine - I can open up some windows and have them talk to each other. However, when I try to deploy the app to Heroku, the clients no longer connect to the server.

Server-side:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}`);
});

const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = socket(http, {
    pingInterval: 100,
    pingTimeout: 500,
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    },
});

io.listen(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    const id = socket.handshake.query.id;
    socket.join(id);

    console.log(`A user has connected with ID ${id}`);
});
```

I deployed the server to a Heroku dyne, and it built successfully. The client is a separate dyne:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const SocketContext = React.createContext();

export function useSocket() {
    return useContext(SocketContext);
}

export function SocketProvider({ id, children }) {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        // const newSocket = io('https://my-heroku-app.herokuapp.com:48600', {
        const newSocket = io('http://localhost:8080', {
            query: { id },
        });
        setSocket(newSocket);

        return () => newSocket.close();
    }, [id]);

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>{children}</SocketContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

This also built successfully. Obviously, localhost:8080 doesn't work when deployed to Heroku - I tried using 'https://my-heroku-app.herokuapp.com:48600' (the server application's name plus the port where it's running on Heroku), and that doesn't work either. The console.log never occurs on the server side when I do heroku logs --tail.

Is there a better way to do this? Can I put these into the same app, so I only have to deploy one project?

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I'm having the same issue more or less

Comment: I have not, unfortunately.

Comment: I ended up fixing it in the end, the node server needed to be on a separate app and it works fine now.